# How to fix Error=MissingRegistration in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firebase-notifications

index.html

```
<html>
<title>Firebase Messaging Demo</title>
<style>
    div {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="token"></div>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <div id="notis"></div>
    <div id="err"></div>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <!-- For an optimal experience using Cloud Messaging, also add the Firebase SDK for Analytics. -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script>
        MsgElem = document.getElementById("msg");
        TokenElem = document.getElementById("token");
        NotisElem = document.getElementById("notis");
        ErrElem = document.getElementById("err");
        // Initialize Firebase
        // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
        var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyCi6tjFP-VV71i__mHWgAN3uHkV3QXpPQv",
            authDomain: "my-app-3ab21.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://my-app-3ab21.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "my-app-3ab21",
            storageBucket: "my-app-3ab21.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "368038679727",
            appId: "1:368038679725:web:fb79116bcac4c6894be225"
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging
            .requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                MsgElem.innerHTML = "Notification permission granted." 
                console.log("Notification permission granted.");
                
                // get the token in the form of promise
                return messaging.getToken()
            })
            .then(function(token) {
                TokenElem.innerHTML = "token is : " + token
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                ErrElem.innerHTML =  ErrElem.innerHTML + "; " + err
                console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
            });

        messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
            console.log("Message received. ", payload);
            NotisElem.innerHTML = NotisElem.innerHTML + JSON.stringify(payload);
            //kenng - foreground notifications
            const {title, ...options} = payload.notification;
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
                registration.showNotification(title, options);
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

curl-test(shell script)

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=AAAAVbDQlK0:APA91bGz7rxEi96dfTvCaHoqx0za_mNZzLEuqdebRuJ_h2Cv1zbuKqkBJvXaCA5nuBiSmiYqQX0p6sUqZIbT_x9mgDf_0MrTg2fYeG0ecng5dmygJVckdYp_fha969Rfn4jTQ7G30yJx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d '{
  "data": {
    "notification": {
        "title": "FCM Message",
        "body": "This is an FCM Message",
        "icon": "/itwonders-web-logo.png",
    }
  },
  "to": "<DEVICE_REGISTRATION_TOKEN>"
}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

I am create a web application push notification using FCM when I run it then ask me to `allow or block` notification and when I allow notification then it show token and a message `Notification permission granted.` but when I try to push notification to get message of `curl` file through `Postman` then it through an error i.e. `Error=MissingRegistration`.

[image]

So, How can I fix this? Please help me.

Thank You